# Need a bit of clarification of what the question is asking?

Tags: solution-verification

Suppose a and b are positive integers. Consider the following statement P:

If 4 ∤ a and 4 ∤ b then 4 ∤ ab.
Write down the converse and contrapositive of P. Which of the three statements — P itself, the
converse of P, and the contrapositive of P — are true and which false. For the true statements
provide a proof, and for the false statements a counterexample.

What I got is the converse of P is 4∤ a.b then 4 ∤ a and 4∤ b
for the contrapostive of P is 4 divides a and 4 divides b, then 4 divides a.b

So are the true statments P and the contrapositive of P? or am I not reading the statement properly??

Edit, There was a mistake with the contrapositive statement.
Is the new one If 4 Divides a.b then 4 divides a or 4 divides b?

Would this change which statement is true?

Comment: Remember the negation of "p and q" is "not p or not q."

Comment: You have errors.  Recall your definitions and your logic laws.  Your converse is correct of $P$, but your contrapositive is not for multiple reasons.  Recall that the contrapositive of $A\implies B$ would be that $\neg B\implies \neg A$.  Recall also that $\neg (p\wedge q) = (\neg p)\vee (\neg q)$

Comment: As for whether or not $P$ or it's contrapositive is true... note that $4$ does not divide $6$ and that $4$ does not divide $2$ but $4$ does divide $6\times 2$.  Note also that the truth of an implication $P$ is always equivalent to the truth of the contrapositive of $P$

Answer (score 1):

You've mostly understood the question but you need to remember that the contrapositive of a statement $P \implies Q$ is $\neg Q \implies \neg P$. For example If my statement is "If a shape is a square then it is a rectangle" the contrapositive is "If a shape is not a rectangle then it is not a square".

Comment: I see that now, thank you!, so would the new one be;  if 4 does divde a.b then 4 divdes a or 4 divides b ?

Comment: @HasBeen22: Yes, correct. But put more effort into your spelling and punctuation.

Comment: @user21820 yeah, noted.